# проверить системное время с++

Tags: c++, visual-studio

Как проверить системное время и если оно равно например 12:46, написать в консоль?

Comment: У вас возникли сложности со сравнением или с выводом в консоль?

Comment: со сравнением конечно

Comment: Тогда категорически рекомендую почитать базовые книги по C/C++ и узнать из них, что для сравнения применяется, например, оператор ==

Comment: спасибо что не ответили на мой вопрос и потратили наше время

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно воспользоваться функцией `GetSystemTime` из `WinApi` например.

```
SYSTEMTIME time;
::GetSystemTime(&time);
if (time.wHour == 12 && time.wMinute == 46)
{
  //...
}
```

Comment: Но не стоит, поскольку она: 
1) никакого отношения не имеет к C++
2) непереносима.

Answer (score 0):

Вот две мудрые ссылки:

1. [Функция time: возвращает текущее календарное время в секундах](http://cppstudio.com/post/597/)
2. [Функция localtime Функция преобразовывает текущее значение времени, передаваемое как аргумент, через указатель timeptr на time_t в структуру tm.](http://cppstudio.com/post/616/)